Driver's license in Canada with exchange application abroad
I submitted a driver's license exchange application in Norway, so my Canadian driver's license is being held at the local office. However, I won't be able to get a Norwegian driver's license on time due to the unavailability of time slots to take a practical test. Now I have plans to travel to Canada soon, but if I take my Canadian driver's license back from the Norwegian office, I will have to submit the driver's license exchange application again later on, but because the rules in Norway changed while my application was still in process, resubmitting the application will require taking several additional traffic courses.
So, what are my options? Can I still request a replacement of my driver's license in Canada when I come there for a visit?

Assuming you are living in Norway, our [expatriates.se] site would be better for this.
